# What does $Pr(dx,dy)$ mean in this notation?

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is equation 2.10 from the book Elements of Statistical Learning:

$$
E[(Y-f(X))^2] = \int (y-f(X))^2Pr(dx,dy)
$$

$X$ is a real valued random input vector and $Y$ is a real valued random output. $X$ and $Y$ have joint distribution $Pr(X,Y)$. $f(X)$ is an approximation of $Y$ for a given $X$.

I am confused by the $dx$ and $dy$ within $Pr$ in the integral. Does $Pr(dx,dy)$ mean the probability of $X$ and $Y$ lying in the $dx$ and $dy$ ranges, respectively?

Is the integral equivalent to
$$
E[(Y-f(X))^2] = \int (y-f(X))^2 p(x,y) dx,dy
$$
where $p(x,y)$ is the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: This is the two variable version of what's happening in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512393/meaning-of-int-e-fx-mudx Where $\int_E f \; d\mu = \int_E f(x) \; \mu(dx) = \int_E f(x) \; d\mu(x)$ are various notations for the Lebesgue integral. If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with density $p(x)$ then $\int_E f \;d\mu = \int_E f(x)p(x) \;dx$. The same is true for your question just with two variables.